# Ruby ActiveRecord 2 level join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This should be a very basic question, I'm still new to ruby so i'd appreciate some help.

So I have 3 tables in my db, Source, SourceType and Feed. Every Source belongs to a SourceType and Every Feed Belongs to a Source. Their primary keys are SourceID, TypeID and FeedID

my Active Record Classes are:

```
class SourceFeed < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "SourceFeed"
  self.primary_key = "FeedID"

  belongs_to :Source, 
  :foreign_key => "SourceID", 
  :class_name => "Source",
  :include => "SourceType"
end

class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "Source"
  self.primary_key = "SourceID"

  has_many :SourceFeeds, 
  :primary_key => "SourceID", 
  :class_name => "SourceFeed"

  belongs_to :SourceType,
  :foreign_key => "TypeID", 
  :class_name => "SourceType"
end

class SourceType < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "SourceType"
  self.primary_key = "TypeID"

  has_many :Source, 
  :primary_key => "TypeID", 
  :class_name => "Source"
end
```

I am trying to select stuff from SourceFeed, Stuff from Source and the SourceType. Here's the query:

```
feed = SourceFeed.select("SourceFeed.FeedID, Source.Name as SourceName, SourceType.Name as SourceType").joins(:Source, :SourceType).where(:FeedID => FeedID).first
```

I am getting a `Association named 'SourceType' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?` Error

If I remove it from the Joins, I get an `Unknown column 'SourceType.Name' in 'field list'` error.

What's the right way to do it?

Thanks

PS: My database doesn't follow active records naming conventions, but I can't change that I am working with an existing DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query only works if there's an association named "SourceType" defined in SourceFeed. You don't have it, so you got the error.
I think this should work:

```
feed = SourceFeed.select("SourceFeed.FeedID, Source.Name as SourceName, SourceType.Name as SourceType").joins(:Source).joins("JOIN SourceType ON SourceType.TypeID = Source.TypeID").where(:FeedID => FeedID).first
```

**UPDATE**:
Definitely, Derek Harmel's answer is a better one. SQL should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: It worked thanks :) the 2nd joins should read `joins("JOIN SourceType ON SourceType.TypeID = Source.TypeID")`

Answer (score 6):

Try changing the joins arguments from

```
.joins(:Source, :SourceType)
```

to

```
.joins(:Source => :SourceType)
```

Also, it should be mentioned that your association names should probably be lowercased in your model definitions.

Comment: That worked as well. Thanks. Is the lowercasing just a convention or does it affect something?

Comment: Convention for sure, but it may have some consequences as well, but I can't say for certain. Typically Ruby reserves uppercasing for constants, classes, and modules. You'll end up with some funny looking code, e.g. source.SourceType is definitely not idiomatic.